# Adding more space to a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

Sending out the cat  signal I need to get what's on the screenshot. I've tried by playing with scale but I've failed. Could you give me a hand?

[image]

Mine looks horrible :(

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \sffamily
        \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{rc}
            & \hspace{15mm} Movies \\
        Users &\centering%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
            \begin{tabular}{ l |>{\centering}p{2cm}| r }
                &      A    &   B  \\ \hline
                1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ & ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
                2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
            \end{tabular}  
        \end{tabular}
    \end{adjustbox}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[stealth-stealth,black] (a11.north east) --  (a12.north west)
        node[midway,above,scale=0.7,black] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
        \draw[-stealth,black] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south   west);
        \draw[-stealth,black,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
        \draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
        node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.7,black] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
        \draw[-stealth,densely dotted] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a matrix of nodes. You can make it larger or smaller by increasing or deceasing `\mylength`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \def\mylength{4em}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=\mylength,inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
 cells={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}](mat){
    & A & B \\
  1 & $r_{1A}$ & $r_{1B}$\\
  2 & $r_{2A}$ & $r_{2B}$\\};
  \foreach \X in {1,2}{
  \path (mat-\X-3.south) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax-3.north) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxH-\X)
    (mat-2-\X.east) -- (mat-2-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.west) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxV-\X);
  \draw (mat.west|-auxH-\X) -- (mat.east|-auxH-\X);
  \draw (mat.north-|auxV-\X) -- (mat.south-|auxV-\X);}
  \draw (mat.south west) -- (mat.south east);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (mat-2-2.north east) --  (mat-2-3.north west)
   node[midway,above,scale=0.7] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
  \draw[-stealth] (mat-3-2.south east) -- (mat-3-3.south   west);
  \draw[-stealth] (mat-2-3) -- (mat-3-3) coordinate[pos=1/3](aux);
  \draw[-stealth,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] ++ (1em,-1em)
  to[out=-100,in=90]
  ([xshift=3pt]dAB.south|-mat-3-3);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (mat-2-2.south east) -- (mat-3-2.east)
    node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.7] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
  \draw[-stealth,densely dotted] (d12.north) to[out=10,in=170] ++ (2em,1em)
  to[out=-10,in=180]   (aux);
  \node[above] at (auxV-2|-mat.north){Movies};
  \node[left] at (auxH-2-|mat.west){Users};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It gets complicated when you want to add the movies and users labels

Comment: @NaveganTeX Not at all, I just missed to add them. It is very easy.

Answer (score 4):

Add `dashed` for dashed lines:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \sffamily
        \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular}{rc}
            & Movies \\
            Users &\centering%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
            \begin{tabular}{ l |>{\centering}p{1cm}| r }
                &      A    &   B  \\ \hline
                1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ & ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
                2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
            \end{tabular}  
        \end{tabular}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[stealth-stealth,blue] (a11.north east) --  (a12.north west)
        node[midway,above,scale=0.7,black] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
        \draw[-stealth,blue] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south   west);
        \draw[-stealth,blue,dashed] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
        \draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
        node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.7,black] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
        \draw[-stealth,dashed] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or `densely dotted`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \sffamily
        \centering\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \begin{tabular}{rc}
            & Movies \\
            Users &\centering%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}
            \begin{tabular}{ l |>{\centering}p{1cm}| r }
                &      A    &   B  \\ \hline
                1 & $\tikzmarknode{a11}{r_{1A}}$~ & ~$\tikzmarknode{a12}{r_{1B}}$ \\ \hline
                2 & $\tikzmarknode{a21}{r_{2A}}$~  & ~$\tikzmarknode{a22}{r_{BA}}$ \\ \hline  
            \end{tabular}  
        \end{tabular}

        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw[stealth-stealth,blue] (a11.north east) --  (a12.north west)
        node[midway,above,scale=0.7,black] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
        \draw[-stealth,blue] (a21.south east) -- (a22.south   west);
        \draw[-stealth,blue,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] (dAB.south|-a22);
        \draw[stealth-stealth] (a11.east) -- (a21.east)
        node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.7,black] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
        \draw[-stealth,densely dotted] (d12.north) to[out=0,in=180] ([yshift=-1ex]a12.west);
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Maeve! It looks fantastic!