# Fixing label position

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to put dAB and d12 as they appear in this screenshot. 
I tried to do it by myself but whenever I move dAB or d12, the arrows move along with it. I would also like to increase the size of the tip of the arrow, as it appears in the screenshot. The actual MWE looks bigger than the one in the screenshot. How can I make it look the same size? The distance between each element of the matrix is shorter and the arrows look thicker. 
[image]

The MWE I am providing was created by the [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/512231/185467)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \def\mylength{4em}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=\mylength,inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
 cells={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}](mat){
    & A & B \\
  1 & $r_{1A}$ & $r_{1B}$\\
  2 & $r_{2A}$ & $r_{2B}$\\};
  \foreach \X in {1,2}{
  \path (mat-\X-3.south) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax-3.north) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxH-\X)
    (mat-2-\X.east) -- (mat-2-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.west) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxV-\X);
  \draw (mat.west|-auxH-\X) -- (mat.east|-auxH-\X);
  \draw (mat.north-|auxV-\X) -- (mat.south-|auxV-\X);}
  \draw (mat.south west) -- (mat.south east);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (mat-2-2.north east) --  (mat-2-3.north west)
   node[midway,above,scale=0.7] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
  \draw[-stealth] (mat-3-2.south east) -- (mat-3-3.south   west);
  \draw[-stealth] (mat-2-3) -- (mat-3-3) coordinate[pos=1/3](aux);
  \draw[-stealth,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] ++ (1em,-1em)
  to[out=-100,in=90]
  ([xshift=3pt]dAB.south|-mat-3-3);
  \draw[stealth-stealth] (mat-2-2.south east) -- (mat-3-2.east)
    node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.7] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
  \draw[-stealth,densely dotted] (d12.north) to[out=10,in=170] ++ (2em,1em)
  to[out=-10,in=180]   (aux);
  \node[above] at (auxV-2|-mat.north){Movies};
  \node[left] at (auxH-2-|mat.west){Users};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `pos=0.5` sets the position to halfway. Set it to whatever value you want (between 0 and 1). Similarly, substitute `pos=<value>` for `midway` in the other case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @cfr's saying, you can put stuff in the middle by using `midway` or `pos=0.5`. The thickness of the arrows can be controlled with `arrows.meta`. I also added a second version where the arrows really run between the nodes without shifts.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \def\mylength{4em}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=\mylength,inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
 cells={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}](mat){
    & A & B \\
  1 & $r_{1A}$ & $r_{1B}$\\
  2 & $r_{2A}$ & $r_{2B}$\\};
  \foreach \X in {1,2}{
  \path (mat-\X-3.south) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax-3.north) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxH-\X)
    (mat-2-\X.east) -- (mat-2-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.west) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxV-\X);
  \draw (mat.west|-auxH-\X) -- (mat.east|-auxH-\X);
  \draw (mat.north-|auxV-\X) -- (mat.south-|auxV-\X);}
  \draw (mat.south west) -- (mat.south east);
  \begin{scope}[thick,>={Stealth[width=6pt,bend]}]
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2.north east) --  (mat-2-3.north west)
    node[midway,above,scale=0.7] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
   \draw[->] (mat-3-2.south east) -- (mat-3-3.south   west);
   \draw[->] (mat-2-3) -- (mat-3-3) coordinate[pos=1/3](aux);
   \draw[->,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] ++ (1em,-1em)
    to[out=-100,in=90]
    ([xshift=3pt]dAB.south|-mat-3-3);
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2.south east) -- (mat-3-2.east)
     node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.5] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
   \draw[->,densely dotted] (d12.north) to[out=10,in=170] ++ (2em,1em)
    to[out=-10,in=180]   (aux);
  \end{scope} 
  \node[above] at (auxV-2|-mat.north){Movies};
  \node[left] at (auxH-2-|mat.west){Users};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \def\mylength{4em}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=\mylength,inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
 cells={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}](mat){
    & A & B \\
  1 & $r_{1A}$ & $r_{1B}$\\
  2 & $r_{2A}$ & $r_{2B}$\\};
  \foreach \X in {1,2}{
  \path (mat-\X-3.south) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax-3.north) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxH-\X)
    (mat-2-\X.east) -- (mat-2-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax.west) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxV-\X);
  \draw (mat.west|-auxH-\X) -- (mat.east|-auxH-\X);
  \draw (mat.north-|auxV-\X) -- (mat.south-|auxV-\X);}
  \draw (mat.south west) -- (mat.south east);
  \begin{scope}[thick,>={Stealth[width=6pt,bend]}]
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2) --  (mat-2-3)
    node[midway,above,scale=0.7] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
   \draw[->] (mat-3-2) -- (mat-3-3);
   \draw[->] (mat-2-3) -- (mat-3-3) coordinate[pos=1/3](aux);
   \draw[->,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] ++ (1em,-1em)
    to[out=-100,in=90]
    ([xshift=3pt]dAB.south|-mat-3-3);
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2) -- (mat-3-2)
     node[pos=0.5,right,scale=0.5] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
   \draw[->,densely dotted] (d12.north) to[out=10,in=170] ++ (2em,1em)
    to[out=-10,in=180]   (aux);
  \end{scope} 
  \node[above] at (auxV-2|-mat.north){Movies};
  \node[left] at (auxH-2-|mat.west){Users};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are two more suggestions:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,bending}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \def\mylength{4em}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=\mylength,inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
 cells={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}](mat){
    & A & & B \\
  1 & $r_{1A}$ & & $r_{1B}$\\
  2 & $r_{2A}$ & & $r_{2B}$\\};
  \foreach \X/\Y in {1/2,2/4}{ 
  \path (mat-\X-4.south) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax-4.north) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxH-\X)
  (mat-2-\X.east) -- (mat-2-\Y.west) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxV-\X);
  \draw (mat.west|-auxH-\X) -- (mat.east|-auxH-\X);
  \draw (mat.north-|auxV-\X) -- (mat.south-|auxV-\X);}
  \draw (mat.south west) -- (mat.south east);
  \begin{scope}[thick,>={Stealth[width=6pt,bend]}]
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2.north east) --  (mat-2-4.north west)
    node[pos=0.7,above] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
   \draw[->] (mat-3-2.south east) -- (mat-3-4.south   west);
   \draw[->] (mat-2-4) -- (mat-3-4) coordinate[pos=1/3](aux);
   \draw[->,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] ++ (1em,-1em)
    to[out=-100,in=90]
    ([xshift=3pt]dAB.south|-mat-3-4);
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2.south east) -- (mat-3-2.east)
     node[pos=0.7,right] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
   \draw[->,densely dotted] ([yshift=-1ex]mat-2-2.south east) to[out=10,in=170] ++ (2em,1em)
    to[out=-10,in=180]   (aux);
  \end{scope} 
  \node[above] at (auxV-2|-mat.north){Movies};
  \node[left] at (auxH-2-|mat.west){Users};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \def\mylength{4em}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=3em,row sep=\mylength,inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
 cells={nodes={inner sep=2pt}}](mat){
    & A & & B \\
  1 & $r_{1A}$ & & $r_{1B}$\\
  2 & $r_{2A}$ &  & $r_{2B}$\\};
  \foreach \X/\Y in {1/2,2/4}{ 
  \path (mat-\X-4.south) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\X+1\relax-4.north) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxH-\X)
  (mat-2-\X.east) -- (mat-2-\Y.west) 
    coordinate[midway] (auxV-\X);
  \draw (mat.west|-auxH-\X) -- (mat.east|-auxH-\X);
  \draw (mat.north-|auxV-\X) -- (mat.south-|auxV-\X);}
  \draw (mat.south west) -- (mat.south east);
  \begin{scope}[thick,>={Stealth[width=6pt,bend]}]
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2) --  (mat-2-4)
    node[pos=0.7,above] (dAB)    {\contour{white}{$d_{AB}$}};
   \draw[->] (mat-3-2) -- (mat-3-4);
   \draw[->] (mat-2-4) -- (mat-3-4) coordinate[pos=1/3](aux);
   \draw[->,densely dotted] (dAB.south) to[out=0,in=80] ++ (1em,-1em)
    to[out=-100,in=90]
    ([xshift=3pt]dAB.south|-mat-3-4);
   \draw[<->] (mat-2-2) -- (mat-3-2)
     node[pos=0.7,right] (d12) {\contour{white}{$d_{12}$}};
   \draw[->,densely dotted] ([yshift=-2ex]mat-2-2.south east) to[out=10,in=170] ++ (2em,1em)
    to[out=-10,in=180]   (aux);
  \end{scope} 
  \node[above] at (auxV-2|-mat.north){Movies};
  \node[left] at (auxH-2-|mat.west){Users};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @NaveganTeX Yes, I added some suggestions.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I would add `$r_{2\text{A}}$ ` since those letter are not in math mode.

Answer (score 3):

You can position the edge labels on the edge with `pos=<fraction of edge length>` (as mentioned @cfr in her comment). With little modifications to your MWE (such as using the `quaotes` package for edge labels, probably incorrect guessing, where the lines between nodes in matrix should be, etc) the MWE can be:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                calc, matrix,
                quotes}
\usepackage{contour}
\contourlength{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   > = Stealth,
font = \sffamily,
every edge quotes/.style = {font=\sffamily\scriptsize,inner sep=1pt, auto}
                        ]
 \def\mylength{4em}

\matrix (m)    [matrix of nodes,
                nodes in empty cells,
                column sep=\mylength,
                row sep=\mylength,
                inner sep=0.5*\mylength,
                cells={nodes={minimum size=1.2em, anchor=center, inner sep=1pt}},
                ]
{
    & A         & B         \\
 1  & $r_{1A}$  & $r_{1B}$  \\
 2  & $r_{2A}$  & $r_{2B}$  \\
};
\foreach \i in {1,2} 
{
\path   (m-\i-3.south) -- (m-\the\numexpr\i+1\relax-3.north)
        coordinate[midway] (H-\i)
        (m-2-\i.east) -- (m-2-\the\numexpr\i+1\relax.west)
        coordinate[midway] (V-\i);
\draw[shorten >=-1ex]   (m.north -| V-\i) -- (m.south -| V-\i);
\draw                   (m.west  |- H-\i) -- (m.east  |- H-\i);
}
\draw   (m.south west)  -- (m.south east);
%
\node[above] at (V-2|-m.north)  {Movies};
\node[left]  at (H-2-|m.west)   {Users};
%
\draw[<->]  (m-2-2.north east) 
    to[pos=0.7,"$d_\mathit{AB}$"{name=dAB}] 
            (m-2-3.north west);
\draw[<->]  (m-2-2.south east)
    to[pos=0.2, "$d_{12}$"{name=d12}]   
            (m-3-2.north east);
%
\draw[->] (m-3-2.east) -- (m-3-3.west);
\draw[->] (m-2-3.south) -- (m-3-3.north) coordinate[pos=0.3] (aux);
%
\draw[->,densely dotted]    
            (dAB.south) 
    .. controls +(2em,-0.5em) and +(0,2em) ..
            ($(m-3-2.east)!0.6!(m-3-3.west)$);
\draw[->,densely dotted] 
            (d12.north east) 
    .. controls +(2em,1em) and +(-1em,1em) ..
            (aux);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]